# Convert Grid square numbers to coordanates

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid, coordinates, converters

How in JavaScript, would I convert a grid square number on, say a 4x4 grid, and easily convert it to grid coordinates? (Example: grid square #6 -> 2, 2)

^ = selected square

```
[][][][]
[][^][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

So basically, how do I (quickly?) convert a grid number to two coordinates.
Is there some small algorithm to do this without a variable or array for each and every grid square. What I need, is to be able to do this, though in a array that's at least 1,000+ grid squares.

The reason for this is I am using the HTML5 canvas, and need to turn a grid number, into two coordinates, for drawing "pixels" (tiny squares), and I must keep track of them(with an object array), if that helps. 
    Is this even possible? Please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the division and the module of that number by the array length:

6 / 4 = 1

(6 % 4)-1 = 1

Remember that arrays start at 0, so the 6th position is (1, 1)

```
[][][][]
[][^][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```